# Find matrix P that places A into its Jordan canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, jordan-normal-form

The following matrix has zero eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity four,

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 &0&0&0\\0&0&-1&1 \\-1&-1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Find P so that $P^{-1}AP=J$, where J is in Jordan normal form.

Solution: I found the three generalized eigenvectors, and 2 of the normal eigenvectors.

Comment: One also can just solve $AP=PJ$ for the entries of $P$ and chose an invertible solution. This is pretty easy and just a direct computation.

Comment: I do not follow sorry, I basically found all the eigenvectors I needed to show that $Ax^{2}x_6 = 0$ and $Ax^{3}x_6 \ne 0$. But we need to show linear independence now, and I have no clue how to do that part.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "don't follow your way using eigenvectors". Just solve linear equations in the unknowns of $P$.

Comment: rudin, I am working on an answer by construction. Of course, he is correct in that putting a matrix $P$ of 36 explicit variables will be faster. I suggest doing both ways, things to be learned...

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback Dietrich and Will. I look forward to seeing the construction.

Comment: The $4\times4$ matrix with which you replaced the original $6\times6$ matrix has $0$, $1$ and $-1$ as eigenvalues, and it is diagonalizable as well. You really shouldn't change your question like this after you’ve already gotten an answer to the original version. It makes the answer nonsensical. If you want to ask about a different matrix, then post a new question.

Comment: @amd i know, I am trying to fix it back, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love these. The characteristic polynomial is $x^6$ while the minimal polynomial is $x^3.$ Since you confirmed dimension $3$ of genuine eigenvectors ( perhaps with row echelon form) this settles the overall shape. There is a 3 by 3 Jordan block, the a 2 by 2, then a singleton. So, $A^3= 0,$ but $A^2 \neq 0.$ For the 3 by 3 block, we want a (nonzero) vector $w$ such that $A^2 w \neq 0.$ 
The easy way to find $w,$ which will be a column vector, is $(0,0,0,0,0,1)^T,$ the transpose of the displayed row vector. Then $v = Aw$  and $u = Av = A^2 w$ is a genuine eigenvector, as $Au = A^2v = A^3 w = 0.$ The $u,v,w$ are the three right-hand columns of $P.$

so far we have 
$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
? & ? & ? &0 & 0 & 0 \\
? & ? & ? &-1 & 1 & 0 \\
? & ? & ? &-1 & 1 & 0 \\
? & ? & ? &0 & 0 & 0 \\
? & ? & ? & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
? & ? & ? &0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Good start; For the 2 by 2 block, we need  vector $t$ with $At \neq 0$ but $A^2 t = 0.$ Then $s=At$ is a genuine eigenvector. However, we need to ensure that $s,t$ are INDEPENDENT of $u,v,w,$ which is not guaranteed as they have the same eigenvalue.
The kernel of $A^2$ can be anything we want, as long as the sixth entry is zero. Looking at $u,v,w,$ the three right-hand columns, we also have freedom in the first and fourth entries. I took $t = (0,0,0,1,0,0)^T.$ Then $s = At = (0,0,1,0,0,0)^T$ uses just the third entry.  We reach columns stuvw, or
$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
? & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
? & 0 & 0 &-1 & 1 & 0 \\
? & 1 & 0 &-1 & 1 & 0 \\
? & 0 & 1 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
? & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
? & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Finally, we need a genuine eigenvector $r$ that is independent of everything so far, although just the first two eigenvectors su will be involved. Alright, drawing some pictures, we can have what we like in the first and fourth entries... indeed, we o get  independence. So, $r = (1,0,0,1,0,0)^T$

$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &-1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
With so many zero elements, various ways to invert..

$$
P^{-1} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 &1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you will for all the construction done for this problem. I really appreciate and I believe I'm starting to understand how you showed independence. Thanks!